# How to understand this example of cat?

Tags: clojure, cat

There is an example of cat in clojuredocs.com

```clj
(into [] (comp cat cat (map inc)) [[[1] [2]] [[3] [4]]])
```

As I know, `comp` applies fn left to right but above example seem to be applied right to left. How can I read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `comp`-ing [transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) runs them basically left-to-right.

From above docs:

> Transducers compose with ordinary function composition. A transducer performs its operation before deciding whether and how many times to call the transducer it wraps. The recommended way to compose transducers is with the existing comp function:
>
> ```clj
> (def xf
>   (comp
>     (filter odd?)
>     (map inc)
>     (take 5)))
> ```
>
> The transducer xf is a transformation stack that will be applied by a process to a series of input elements. Each function in the stack is performed before the operation it wraps. **Composition of the transformer runs right-to-left but builds a transformation stack that runs left-to-right (filtering happens before mapping in this example)**.
>
> As a mnemonic, remember that the ordering of transducer functions in comp is the same order as sequence transformations in ->>. The transformation above is equivalent to the sequence transformation:
>
> ```clj
> (->> coll
>      (filter odd?)
>      (map inc)
>      (take 5))
> ```

Comment: Thanks @cfrick ! `Composition of the transformer runs right-to-left but builds a transformation stack that runs left-to-right` that is the key point!

Answer (score 2):

The "secret" is in `comp` function, which applies functions right to left, but for [transducers it is left to right](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers#_using_transducers).

Since you are transducing, `(comp cat cat (map inc))` is kinda like
`(fn [xs] (map inc (sequence cat (sequence cat xs))))` (note, there is no version of `cat` that takes a coll)

Comment: I don't think this is "equal to".  `cat` is always a transducer and expects a reducing function; then you mix that with the regular map syntax like passing in a sequence.

Comment: You're right, it is not. It's more like "something like that'. Let me fix that.

Comment: Nope, still not. A "close thing" would be using `(sequence cat ...)` now (intead of the `concat` right now) (or `apply concat`)

Comment: I was meant to write `apply concat`.

Comment: @akond Thanks a lot! it was very helpful :) `Transducer` is the key.